# PHP sessions not working in some pages only

Tags: php, session

I have some pages on a website. All pages do have a bar, which I put with the following:

```
session_start();
include('bar.php');
echo $bar;
```

where the content of bar.php is more or less this:

```
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
if empty($username) {
    $bar='You are not logged in.';
} else {
    $bar='You are logged in.';
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the bar works (i.e. it shows "logged in" when I actually am), but sometimes it doesn't (it shows content for non-logged users). For example, browsing the index I see the bar for non-logged users, but going on the login page shows me the bar for logged users.

Also, I tried deleting my PHPSESSID  cookie and then logging in: it worked, it didn't show this bug. Why?

Comment: Can you remove the session_start() from bar.php and try again?

Comment: does it happen in all browsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second session_start(); simply is ignored, so I think this is not the problem. You could check if session_start() returns false: http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: I tested the second session_start();, but it returns 1 (true), which is successful.